# Plex not detecting media on Amazon S3 mounted with S3QL

Tags: mount, permissions, media, mediaserver, plex

So I have had a Plex server for a while now, and it has been running on a Dell Poweredge 2850 and Dell Powervault 220s. Ever since this server has been running, our power bill has been way more than usual for an obvious reason. I recently decided to test migrating everything to the cloud just to make everything a lot simpler, and for a fun project. I am now trying to use Amazon S3 for file storage and Digital Ocean with Ubuntu 14.04 to host the transcoding computer. I have had partial success, but am having trouble getting Plex to discover any media on the mounted S3 drive. I use transmit to SFTP to the Droplet from Digital Ocean and see the mounted S3 folder and media, but when I pull up Plex and point it to the destination, it doesn't see anything inside the folder. I am thinking this is a permissions error with the folder, but I ran `chmod 777` for the folder where the S3 bucket was mounted, but Plex still sees nothing in the folder. I tried this with Fuse as well and had the same result, but am going with S3QL because it uploads files in 10mb chunks, so the entire file isn't required to access one part of one file, therefore saving time and bandwidth.

Here are the guides I used:

Plex install: https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/26727-how-to-plex-media-server-on-ubuntu/

S3QL install: http://ubuntuservergui.com/ubuntu-server-guide/mount-s3-ubuntu-server

I also ran `sudo gpasswd -a plex plugdev` to give Plex more permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the --allow-other option when mounting S3QL. The Plex Media Server runs on the plex user, while, by default, mount.s3ql only allows access by the user that mounted the filesystem.

You may also need to modify /etc/fuse.conf to allow other users access, by uncommenting user_allow_other:

```
sudo nano /etc/fuse.conf
```

You may also need to add the user mounting S3QL to the fuse group, then logout and login:

```
sudo adduser USERNAME fuse
```

Explanation of other mount.s3ql options: 
http://www.rath.org/s3ql-docs/mount.html

I run Plex Media Server from a t2.micro instance on Amazon EC2. It's free and works very well.